# ionic 2 send veriable on click div

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

```
    <div class="copkutusu" (click)="kanalsil(kanalid,deneme)" #kanalid id={{ver.channelid}} 
#deneme id={{ver.channelapikey}}></div>
```

I call in .ts , give me kanalid.id and deneme.id same veriable but thats different things

Comment: try to use `kanalid.value` in that parameter

Comment: Try (click)="kanalsil(ver.channelid,ver.channelapikey)"

Comment: thanx @rf_96_rf

Comment: I added answer, for the future users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your div like that:

```
<div class="copkutusu" (click)="kanalsil(ver.channelid,ver.channelapikey)"></div>
```